# Combobox doesn't allow enter custom text if DataBinding is used

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have the following class:

```
class Address
{
     public string City {get; set;}
     public string Street {get; set;}
}
```

and I have a form with 2 comboboxes on it. I bind these comboboxes to Address class:

```
CityComboBox.DataSource = GetCityDataSource();
StreetComboBox.DataSource = GetStreetDataSource();
Address address = new Address();
CityComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", address, "City");
StreetComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", address, "Street");
```

The database of Cities and Streets is not complete, so sometimes user should write custom values to combobox. The problem is - having combobox databindings doesn't allow to write custom values to this combobox. Is there a workaround for this behaviour?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of collection does GetCityDataSource() return?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This works:** (in your case)

Set the `DrowdownStyle` to `Dropdown` and bind to the ComboBox's `Text` property instead of `SelectedItem`.

For the two comboboxes, you appear to want to bind the text to the `City` and `Street` properties of an instance of the `Address` class. You *don't* seem to want to append any items in the `List<string>` returned by the `GetCityDataSource()` or `GetStreetDataSource()` methods.

Therefore, since the `Text` *target* property of the binding below isn't entangled with the ([unchangeable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) items collection associated with your *datasource*, the following modifications should make your code work: (I've verified the essense of the code changes below using VS 2010).

```
 CityComboBox.DataSource = GetCityDataSource(); 
 StreetComboBox.DataSource = GetStreetDataSource(); 
 Address address = new Address(); 
 CityComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
 CityComboBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", address, "City");
 StreetComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
 StreetComboBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", address, "Street");
```

**PS!** The approach above only works when you want to use the City and Street data for simple UI-*guidance*. You are not establishing a permanent relationship between the address data and the objects for which you register an address. If you want to keep your data *normalized* then you would wish to store *foreign keys* to the entries in the City, Street (and perhaps Zipcode) tables.

With user defined street and city names, you will get a lot of fuzzy data (e.g. `Washington DC`, `WASHINGTON D.C.`, `St. Patricks rd.`, `Saint Patrick's road` etc.) which in the future will make it difficult to execute SQL queries using  `WHERE Street = [something]`. With normalized data you would simply do a `WHERE StreetID = [specificID]`.

**EDIT**

If you are trying to do *two* things at the same time within the same UI dialog (both selection of street and city for e.g. a person/company profile *as well as*  maintenance of your application's internal street and city lists), then you have to use a different approach.

The simplest is probably to add a "new city" and a  "new street" button next to your combobox and update the datasource for the combobox when the user has provided the proper input in a dialog.

You could also add a dummy entry to the combobox data source with the string "[add New]", and use special handling when this item is selected. Since this approach involves tampering with the source list for the combo, it can easily get a little messy.

**Sample App**

A sample form with a databound ComboBox which uses a `List<string>` data source

[image]

Key properties after selecting a predefined street

[image]

Key properties after selecting a custom street

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<Address> list;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list = new BindingList<Address>();
        //lets add some example data:
        list.Add(new Address{ City = "London", Street = "Street 111" });
        list.Add(new Address { City = "Barcelona", Street = "Street 222" });
        comboBox1.DataSource = list;

        //I am not sure what you want to show (and what to use as a value). You can change this!
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Street";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "City";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //adding new object to the list:
        string _city = textBox1.Text;
        string _street = textBox2.Text;
        if (_city != String.Empty && _street != String.Empty)
        {
            list.Add(new Address { City = _city, Street = _street });
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
    }
}

class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is textBox1? Where's binding here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert new value into data source (if this is a array resize an array, and add the new value at the new index, if this is a generi list, simply add new item to it).

Comment: What event should I handle to do it? Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

How I do it (I do not use data binding):

- Initialize an instance of `List<T>` (can be `List<Address>` in your case).
- Read the database items into a `List<T>`.
- Populate your combo boxes using the items found in the `List<T>`.
- When a new item is created, insert that item into your database.
- Restart at the top (lends itself to a procedure you can call anytime).

If you must data bind, you could hide the combo box and pop up a text box until the user saves your information, but you'd still need to write to your database and read the data in again.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps handle the keyevents and when they start typing it then adds a new element?

Comment: What exactly should I do? When user going to type New Yourk, for example, I should add new Cities N, Ne, New, New , New Y, ...?

Comment: Use the Leave event of the combobox to confirm the text into the data source. Keep a reference to the currently editing item in the datasource when you are typing.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is - having combobox
>   databindings doesn't allow to write
>   custom values to this combobox. Is
>   there a workaround for this behaviour?

So don't bind it!
Write your own methods to fill combobox and event handler for editing items.